# Read from folder and update the XML tag value

Tags: java, xpath

I have a folder("Container") inside this i have some .txt files which actually contains XML. All files have a common element `<Number>` which i want to increment by 1 for all the XML files. 
any help.

i have done the change for a single .txt file, which is okay:-

```
package ParsingXML;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
public class ReadAndModifyXMLFile {
    public static final String xmlFilePath = "C:\\Users\\PSINGH17\\Desktop\\testFile.txt";

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFilePath);

            // Get employee by tag name
            //use item(0) to get the first node with tag name "employee"
            Node employee = document.getElementsByTagName("employee").item(0);

            // update employee , increment the number
            NamedNodeMap attribute = employee.getAttributes();
            Node nodeAttr = attribute.getNamedItem("number");
String str= nodeAttr.getNodeValue();
System.out.println(str);
int val= Integer.parseInt(str);
System.out.println(val);
val=val+1;
System.out.println(val);
String final_value= String.valueOf(val);
System.out.println(final_value);
            nodeAttr.setTextContent(final_value);

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);

            StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(xmlFilePath));
            transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);



        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException sae) {
            sae.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><company>


<employee number="14">

    <firstname>Pranav</firstname>

    <lastname>Singh</lastname>
    <email>pranav@example.org</email>


    <salary>1000</salary>

</employee>


</company>
```

Comment: Please show what you already tried

Comment: @mnwsmit:- please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this code uses the initial value digits after hash to start the counter.
Then it iterates through all the files in the folder.
The first file will get the initial value, the rest will get incremented values.

```
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.File;

public class TestFile {
    public static final String xmlFileFolder = "C:\\Rahul\\test";
    private static final String initialValue = "450-000-1212";

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        int baseValue = Integer.parseInt(getValueAfterLastDash(initialValue));
        System.out.println("startValue " + baseValue);
        File folder = new File(xmlFileFolder);
        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                Document document = documentBuilder.parse(file);

                Node employee = document.getElementsByTagName("employee").item(0);
                NamedNodeMap attribute = employee.getAttributes();
                Node nodeAttr = attribute.getNamedItem("number");
                System.out.println(getValueBeforeLastDash(initialValue) + baseValue);
                nodeAttr.setTextContent(getValueBeforeLastDash(initialValue) + baseValue);

                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);

                StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(file);
                transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
                baseValue++;
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getValueAfterLastDash(String initialValue) {
        return initialValue.substring(initialValue.lastIndexOf('-') + 1, initialValue.length());
    }

    private static String getValueBeforeLastDash(String initialValue) {
        return initialValue.substring(0, initialValue.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of just simply pasting a block of code, I think it would be great if you could add a short description of what you wrote, changed or added to the code, maybe even why you did what you did.

Comment: @sdotdi i am having a hard time using this site for answering. I end up talking to pranav on call !, will update the answer once i understand how to do it !